# Derailleurs compatible with Shimano Claris ST 2400 Shifters

Tags: shimano, derailleur

I have a 20-year-old Specialized Sequoia 24-speed road bike. When the groupset was last changed on it, the shop fitted a 3-cog chainset (50/39/30) and an 8-cog rear cassette (28/11), a Shimano Claris crankset and Sora FD 3503 front derailleur, a Shimano Tiagra RD 4400 rear derailleur, and Shimano Claris ST 2400 shifters.

The drivetrain is fine - still plenty of life in it.  But I want to replace/upgrade the derailleurs.  Not a massive upgrade, but something that will provide me with smoother shifting and minimise chainrub. And obviously they'd have to be compatible with those shifters.  From what I can see, there seems to be a wide range of compatibility with Shimano components - but I want to be certain.

Can anyone suggest a set of derailleur replacements that would fit my current set up and requirements, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new Shimano rear derailleur compatible with 8 speeds, you can choose the 8-speed Claris R2000 or 9-speed Sora R3000. The cable actuation ratio is the same.

Even older 10-speed Tiagra 4600 has the same actuation ratio.

The Sora is very slightly higher end, but they are very similar. Claris has the cage with the exact width for an 8-speed chain, but the Sora will work as well.

Personally, I would take the Claris as it is optimized for an 8-speed chain.

---

For the front derailleur I would not change what you have if not necessary. There was a slight change in the actuation ratio recently and the new ones are not officially compatible with your shifters. They will work, but you want to optimize the chain rub and the result might be the opposite.

If you do need a replacement for a worn item, I would look for the older models. Like Claris R2400.

---

Also, don't forget to get new cables and cable housings. The difference in shifting quality may be very big. Larger than between an older and newer derailleur.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer, Vladimir F.  Thank you very much.  I will do as you say and go for the Claris R2000 rear and stay with the existing front Sora.  Yes, I'd always replace cables and housings.  I guess some future upgrade with the brifters might give me a few more options.  Thanks again.  Much appreciated.